# How would you remove a line from a batch file once the file has been ran if it is going to run repeatedly after?

Tags: batch-file

*I do not have control over GPO policies where I am at.  This is the only way I can do this*

I have a logon script that is used across our enterprise. This batch file is used to map users to network drives that they have permissions to.  Recently, our NEC command changed the path location for these drives.  I need to push out an updated batch file to replace the one that currently resides in the startup folder on the C:.  The new file has a line that I added ( net use * /delete /y) in order to delete all existing drives that are mapped.  Once this is done, it moves on to the normal portion of the script by mapping all drives accordingly.

The issue that I am running into is that because this file resides on the startup folder, it will continue to run every time a user logs in.  Users do on occasion, manually map drives to their profiles for more specific folder access that is not included in the scripts (we wont modify the script to fit each individual user).  If it continues to run, it will then delete the manually mapped drives every time which will become a major issue.

What I need to do is to allow the batch file to run once, in order to replace the old naming convention pathways.  Once that is done, I would like to delete the net use * /delete line out of the file and then save it so that it will just run normally every time after.  Is this doable?  Is there a way to delete a line out of a batch file once it compeletes running and save it so that the file that is stored on the machine does NOT contain the net use line?

Here is the file as it is currently written, with the delete option written (to delete the existing mapped drives)

```
net use * /delete /y

net user /domain %username% >%userprofile%\mygroups.txt
del %userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt 1> NUL 2> NUL
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=*" %%G IN (%userprofile%\mygroups.txt) DO (ECHO %%G & echo %%H)>>%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwhelpdesk net use V: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Helpdesk" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwhelpdesk net use P: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Techs\TechsOnly" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwhelpdesk net use O: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Techs" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWUSERS net use I: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\IDrive" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWUSERS net use M: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DwngVault" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWUSERS net use N: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\BaseData" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWUSERS net use S: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DesignRvw" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWITADMINS net use O: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Techs" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWITADMINS net use Q: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Users" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWITADMINS net use T: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\HelpDesk" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWITADMINS net use U: "\\\jblm\dpw\jblm" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWITADMINS net use P: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Techs\TechsOnly" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwhousinggroup net use R: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\RCI_Housing" 1> NUL 2> NUL
so
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWOBUDGET net use J: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\lewidfv-lewis\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\Budget" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWOBUDGET net use Q: "\\150.192.16.77\atlasair" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWOESD net use J: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\COE" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwecmd net use K: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\ECMD" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwecmd net use W: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\WinEst" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWOCOE net use J: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\COE" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWOCOE net use K: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\DPW_Retain\ECMD" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwenrdforestry net use F: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Forestry" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==lewispwenrd net use O: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Pollution" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWXCOMPINSP net use Y: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Comp_Inspec" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWXCOMPINSP net use W: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Hazmat" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==LEWIPWXHAZMAT1210 net use W: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Hazmat" 1> NUL 2> NUL

for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==JBLMIMCOMDPWGSO-Admin net use L: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Working" 1> NUL 2> NUL
for /F %%f in (%userprofile%\mygroupsparsed.txt) do if %%f ==JBLMIMCOMDPWGSO-Spt net use L: "\\jblmfs\jblm\dpw\Working" 1> NUL 2> NUL
```

Cheers.

Comment: Why does it bother you to delete the drives every time and remap them.  I work for one of the largest corporations in the world and that is what we do with our login scripts.

Comment: Your script deletes the connections every time a user logs in?  How do you get around manual mappings?

Comment: We don't do a Global Delete like you are doing.  If the Group DataAdmins has predefined  drives for H:, I:, J: and K:, we are deleting the those drives before we remap them.  All of our login scripts are based on location and AD group.

Comment: What really shocks me even more is your login scripts resides on the local computer. They should reside in the netlogon folder of the domain controller.  Your batch file code could be condensed a lot as well but it would be a lot easier to do what you are doing with Vbscript.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control as to where it is stored as they have segregated us pretty good so i am working with what I have to keep the customer happy.

Comment: And if you have changes to this logon script you would have to physically change it on each computer then. That is a maintenance nightmare unless you are pushing this out to the local computers with a GPO. But if you are doing that then you might as well have the login script execute from a GPO.

Comment: I have a script (IF/THEN) that will replace the current logon script with this one.  If i had more control, I would do everything via GPO but atlas, I cannot.

Comment: How is the script getting distributed to all computers in the enterprise if not by GPO?  If you are planning on changing this what is the plan to make this change to hundreds of computers?

Comment: A script is used to transfer the file to the specific folder where it is stored and overwrite the existing file.  This is our only way to get around the restrictive GPO policies that are in place.  

I just wanted to know if  there was a line that could be entered into the batch file that would delete the net use * /delete line so that the whole file would remain but that line would be deleted.